# How to change fragments in sidebar menu, android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, sidebar

When I try to switch my side fragments in the sidebar from one to another it stays fixated on message fragment. The highlight only changes between 2 fragments: forum and message.

My code:

```
 package com.example.ius;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainPub extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_pub);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_draw_open, R.string.nav_draw_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if(savedInstanceState==null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.mainForum);}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mainForum:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.messages:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "I share se", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.support:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.logOut:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

The thing is only logout fragment works, while others don't open. Also, the side question is when I select fragments from the side I can only select Forum and Messaging, in which Forum doesn't change but only the sidebar highlights.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the fragment opening new code:

```
 package com.example.ius;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainPub extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_pub);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_draw_open, R.string.nav_draw_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //NOVO
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ForumFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.mainForum);
        }
    }

    //NOVO
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    Class fragmentClass;

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mainForum:
                fragmentClass = ForumFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.messages:
                fragmentClass = MessageFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.profile:
                fragmentClass = ProfileFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "I share se", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.support:
                fragmentClass = SupportFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = ForumFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        drawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    // ...

   /* @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mainForum:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.messages:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "I share se", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.support:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MessageFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.logOut:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```